# F# Create a sequence of a certain type

Tags: f#, sequence

I am writing some unit tests at the moment and need to replicate a sequence. The sequence is of type (string * string * string). I have tried to recreate this sequence by

```
let aSequence = seq<aType>{ ("ABC","DEF","GHI"); ("JHL","MNO","PQR") }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to specify the type for `(string * string * string)`, F# can infer it. 
You need to use the `yield` keyword. Read more about seq [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx).

```
let aSequence = seq { yield "ABC","DEF","GHI"
                      yield "JHL","MNO","PQR" }
```